# List installed server roles on a Windows 2003 server

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, roles

In Windows 2008 and 2012 I can use WMI (`"Select * From Win32_ServerFeature"`) in an assembly to get the roles, role services and features. This doesn't work for Windows 2003.

Is there a way to get a list of the installed roles from Windows 2003?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the information you need in `sysoc.inf` (the existing configuration file), located in `%systemroot%\inf`. This is the file used by the optional component manager of Windows Server 2003 (`SYSOCMGR.EXE`) that you can find in the `%systemroot%\system32` folder. Also see the post [here](http://sourcewarp.blogspot.be/2012/06/test-httpwww.html) giving some information on SYSOCMGR.EXE and its core dll (`ocmanage.dll`).